# Trying to sort an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I'm trying to sort this associative array in PHP, sorting by field `name`

```
$fonts = array(
    0 => ["index" => 0, "name" => "Arial", "path" => "assets/fonts/arial.ttf"],
    1 => ["index" => 1, "name" => "Times", "path" => "assets/fonts/times.ttf"],
    2 => ["index" => 2, "name" => "Roboto", "path" => "assets/fonts/roboto.ttf"],
    3 => ["index" => 3, "name" => "AlexBrush", "path" => "assets/fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"],
);
```

What I'm trying to do is to sort the entries by name but keep the keys associated with the entry itself, so what I want is:

```
 $fonts = array(
    3 => ["index" => 3, "name" => "AlexBrush", "path" => "assets/fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"],
    0 => ["index" => 0, "name" => "Arial", "path" => "assets/fonts/arial.ttf"],
    2 => ["index" => 2, "name" => "Roboto", "path" => "assets/fonts/roboto.ttf"],
    1 => ["index" => 1, "name" => "Times", "path" => "assets/fonts/times.ttf"],
);
```

Here's the bare minimum code which exposes the problem (PHP ver +7):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}

$fonts = array(
    0 => ["index" => 0, "name" => "Arial", "path" => "assets/fonts/arial.ttf"],
    1 => ["index" => 1, "name" => "Times", "path" => "assets/fonts/times.ttf"],
    2 => ["index" => 2, "name" => "Roboto", "path" => "assets/fonts/roboto.ttf"],
    3 => ["index" => 3, "name" => "AlexBrush", "path" => "assets/fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"],
);

uasort($fonts, "cmp");

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    echo "<br/>".$fonts[$i]["name"];
}
```

I'm using `uasort()` as it's supposed to keep the keys associated while sorting the array. Unfortunately if I print the array I get the same order, that is:

```
Arial
Times
Roboto
AlexBrush
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `sort` by **name** like this way and loop using `foreach()`

```
<?php

$fonts = array(
    0 => ["index" => 0, "name" => "Arial", "path" => "assets/fonts/arial.ttf"],
    1 => ["index" => 1, "name" => "Times", "path" => "assets/fonts/times.ttf"],
    2 => ["index" => 2, "name" => "Roboto", "path" => "assets/fonts/roboto.ttf"],
    3 => ["index" => 3, "name" => "AlexBrush", "path" => "assets/fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"],
);

uasort($fonts, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});

print_r($fonts);

foreach($fonts as $font){
 echo $font["name"].PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comment,

```
 $indexed_array = array_column($fonts,'name','index'); // array column map name by index
 print_r($indexed_array); 
 echo $indexed_array[3];
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/W7BOH

Comment: If I have the index 3 how can I retrieve AlexBrush from the sorted array? Could you please show me how to do it

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini I've **Edited** my answer based on your comment. Have a look again :)

Comment: I get something weird like "A", "T", "R", "A"

Comment: did you put it inside loop?

Comment: ok it's fine now... I didn't understand that the array is sorted correctly, it's the way I loop through it that was wrong. Foreach solved the issue

Comment: OK Sir, best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using...

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    echo "<br/>".$fonts[$i]["name"];
}
```

to print out the values, you are using the index in numerical order to display them.

If instead you used...

```
print_r($fonts);
```

you would see they have been sorted and get...

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [index] => 3
            [name] => AlexBrush
            [path] => assets/fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [name] => Arial
            [path] => assets/fonts/arial.ttf
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [index] => 2
            [name] => Roboto
            [path] => assets/fonts/roboto.ttf
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index] => 1
            [name] => Times
            [path] => assets/fonts/times.ttf
        )

)
```

Or as L. Faros pointed out in the comments, if you used...

```
foreach ( $fonts as $font ) {
    echo "<br/>".$font["name"];
}
```

you would get

```
<br/>AlexBrush<br/>Arial<br/>Roboto<br/>Times
```

Comment: I don't get it, shouldn't PHP threat the $i index I provide as a "key" for my associative array?

Comment: It is, but the key your asking for is 0,1,2,3 - this isn't the same as asking for element in position 0,1,... of the array. You wanted the key to be maintained and it has been.

Comment: Let's say I want to access element key = 3 (AlexBrush). How can I do it in PHP? $font[3] doesn't work as you said, so how can I do it given the 3? I'd like to have something like $alexbrush = $fonts.key(3);

Comment: Might be worth mentionning that if you want to iterate over the array and keep the array ordered by fonts name, you should use `foreach`

Comment: If you want to access the `AlexBrush` element use `echo $fonts[3]["name"];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_column to make the array associative and then sort with ksort (key sort).

```
$fonts = array_column($fonts, null, "name");
ksort($fonts);
$fonts = array_values($fonts);
var_dump($fonts);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["index"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "AlexBrush"
    ["path"]=>
    string(34) "assets/fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["index"]=>
    int(0)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Arial"
    ["path"]=>
    string(22) "assets/fonts/arial.ttf"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["index"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Roboto"
    ["path"]=>
    string(23) "assets/fonts/roboto.ttf"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["index"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Times"
    ["path"]=>
    string(22) "assets/fonts/times.ttf"
  }
}
```

Which means you can iterate the array as you have done in your question.

https://3v4l.org/pJXfp

---

I see that you ask for how to get index 3 name.

In that case, again use array_column to make it associative on the index.

https://3v4l.org/nCtJf

```
$fonts = array_column($fonts, null, "name");
ksort($fonts);
$fonts = array_column($fonts, null, "index");

echo $fonts[3]["name"]; //AlexBrush
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to keep using `for()`, you actually need to re-index the first level keys -- which is no big deal because you still have the original numeric ids preserved in the `index` elements.

Aligning with that logic, there are two different one-liners that I can recommend.

1. `array_multisort(array_column($fonts, 'name'), $fonts);`
2. `usort($fonts, function($a, $b){return $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];});`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tnLrU)